# How I can map class in FluentNHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have two classes

```
public class ProgramObject
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual Commisioning planCommisioning { get; set; }
   public virtual Commisioning factCommisioning { get; set; }
}
public class Commisioning
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal? FirstQuarter { get; set; }
    public virtual ProgramObject planCommisioningRef { get; set; }
    public virtual ProgramObject factCommisioningRef { get; set; }
}
```

and map classes

```
public class ProgramObjectMap : ClassMap<ProgramObject>
{
    public ProgramObjectMap()
    {
        Table("Ipo_ProgramObject");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.SuplyOrgName).Column("SuplyOrgName");
        References(x => x.factPowerCommisioning).Column("factCommisioningID");
        References(x => x.planPowerCommisioning).Column("planCommisioningID");
    }
}
public class CommisioningMap : ClassMap<Commisioning>
    {
        public CommisioningMap()
        {
            Table("Ipo_Commisioning");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
            Map(x => x.FirstQuarter).Column("FirstQuarter");
            HasOne(x => x.factCommisioningRef)
                .Cascade.All();
            HasOne(x => x.planCommisioningRef)
                .Cascade.All();
        }
    }
```

When I try to commit I have an exception "object references an unsaved transient instance". What am I doing wrong with mapping?

To save object I use this code:

```
private static void Save(SessionManager sManager, ProgramObject ProgramObject, IpoConversions conversions)
    {
        sManager.OpenSession();
            var currSession = sManager.CurrentSession;
        using (ITransaction tx = currSession.BeginTransaction())
        {
            currSession.Save(ProgramObject);
            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
```

I think problem in mapping.

Comment: Please show the code you use to save the objects.

Comment: Try adding `.Inverse()` to the `HasOne` mappings.

Comment: HasOne don't have .Inverse()

Comment: Indeed. Try reading through this article: http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one It seems to have exactly your scenario. One thing I saw was that it saves both entities, so you might try to do that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you either need to save the commisionings first or set cascading

```
currSession.Save(ProgramObject.factPowerCommisioning);
currSession.Save(ProgramObject.planPowerCommisioning);

// or

References(x => x.factPowerCommisioning).Column("factCommisioningID").Cascade.All();
References(x => x.planPowerCommisioning).Column("planCommisioningID").Cascade.All();
```